# I want to run a loop with condition and save all outputs as dataframes with different names

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote an function which only depends on a dataframe. The functions output is also a dataframe. I would like make different dataframes according a condition and save them as different datasets with different names. However I couldnt save them as dataframes with different names. Instead i manually do the process. Is there a code which would do the same. It would be much beneficial.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


data1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Oz/Desktop/vintage/vintage1.csv', encoding='latin-1')



product_list=  data1['product_types'].unique()

def vintage_table(df):
df['Disbursement_Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.Disbursement_Date)
df['Closing_Date']=pd.to_datetime(df.Closing_Date)
df['NPL_date']=pd.to_datetime(df.NPL_date, errors='ignore')

df['NPL_date_period']=df.loc[df.NPL_date > '2015-01-01', 'NPL_date'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
df['Dis_date_period'] = df.Disbursement_Date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
df['diff']=((df.NPL_date-df.Disbursement_Date) / np.timedelta64(3, 'M')).round(0)

df=df.groupby(['Dis_date_period','NPL_date_period']).agg({'Dis_amount' : 'sum',  'NPL_amount' : 'sum', 'diff' : 'mean'})
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
df['Vintage_Ratio']=df['NPL_amount']/df['Dis_amount']

table=pd.pivot_table(df,values='Vintage_Ratio',index='Dis_date_period',columns=['diff'],).fillna(0)

return
```

The above is the function

```
#for e in product_list:
#       sub = data1[data1['product_types'] == e]
#       print(sub)

consumer = data1[data1['product_types'] == product_list[0]]
mortgage = data1[data1['product_types'] == product_list[1]]
vehicle = data1[data1['product_types'] == product_list[2]]


table_con = vintage_table(consumer)
table_mor = vintage_table(mortgage)
table_veh = vintage_table(vehicle)
```

I would like to improve this part is there a better way to do the same process?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your `vintage_table()` function return a dataframe instead of just modifying one dataframe over and over and that way you could do this in the second code block:

```
table_con = vintage_table(consumer)
table_mor = vintage_table(mortgage)
table_veh = vintage_table(vechicle)
```